# Probability default calculation

Tags: portfolio, probability, default

I want to calculate default of probability of internal ratings for a particular bank. I have only the following data:

1. Liquidity Ratio

   - short-term assets / short-term liabilities = 2.6
2. Profitability Ratios

   - **ROA** - yearly net profit / average total assets = 26%
   - **Sales growth** - (current sales − previous sales) / previous sales = 31%
   - **Projected debt service capacity** - (Projected Operational Cash − Flow (stress tested for FX risk)) / Total payments toward the bank = 3
3. Solvency Ratios

   - Debt/EBITDA = 0.4
   - Total equity / total assets = 71%

Could you tell me can I calculate the probability default (PD) rate with this data?
How to proceed?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have at least a large data set you can regress against?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot.  If you had a pre-existing model that had been validated and used these variables, then yes you could, but you cannot calculate a probability from one data point and no other source of information.

Subjectively, the short run probability is small as there is massive coverage of short term debt.  Unless there is a hidden liability, it is nearly zero.  If the firm were sued tomorrow, lost in court and the judgment was devastating then it could become insolvent, but it is nearly zero.  The exact value cannot be calculated without other information.  Even for questions such as "will the sun rise tomorrow," there is a small, if trivial possibility some catastrophic and unknown event could happen.  It is just so close to zero that we ignore it.  This is the same for the above.  It is nearly zero, in the very short term.  We do not know if management will change its policies because it is doing so well.

Comment: I need to map the bank's internal credit ratings to the ratings of S&P or some other external organization. I tried to implement the mapping based on default probability rates. Could you recommend me how can I do it, what model to use...?

Comment: I cannot.  I don't know your resources and skills.  Additionally,  bond ratinga are ordinal data, this isn't a trivial task.  Without having extensive information, I am sorry, I cannot help.

Comment: @Sako are you trying to do a validation study or find the default risk for one specific investment?

Comment: I have Bank's internal ratings from 1-7 (1,2,3.....7), and each number has its qualitative and quantitative criteria (above-mentioned criteria and some qualitative criteria, like business activities & market position, management & organisation etc.) and I should map These numbers to S&P Ratings (AAA, BBB.....).

Comment: Do any of your customers have external ratings?

Comment: I think no, but if my customer has, for example, rating "5", we would like to know what rating of S&P or Creditreform this "5" is corresponding to and what is his probability of Default equals to.

Comment: The major three ratings systems do not correspond directly.  There was just an article in the Southwestern Finance Association's journal, whatever its name is, I cannot remember off the top of my head, on Fitch's ratings and how they improve pricing because they contain information not included in the other two systems.  The three only loosely correspond(continued)

Comment: Your better path is either to do model validation on their own models versus their own default rates, or to get data such as Compustat data and validate it against the broad population of corporate data.  They may have some form of customer self-selection that makes their model invalid outside their customer set.  It would be a form of over fitting.  I tested 78 models of bankruptcy and found only two models that were acceptable under a Bayesian model selection regime.  The remaining models were Frequentist statistically significant, but not valid.